# AntMiner S5 chain #2 intermittently operational

Tags: antminer

Why is my AntMiner S5 chain only intermittently operational? What could cause this, how could I diagnose it, and what is the solution? Will BitmainTech replace it for me? How do I know if it's under warranty? Is there a warranty?

[image: AntMiner S5 dead chain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why is my AntMiner S5 chain only intermittently operational?*

It's due to hardware failure.

*Will BitmainTech replace it for me?*

Yes, I had the same issue. I had to pay to ship it back to them, and they very promptly shipped back a replacement board.

*How do I know if it's under warranty?*

Ask them. They're able to figure it out for you.

*Is there a warranty?*

Yes, I believe it's 3 months (90 days).

Answer (score 0):

[Someone](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1033277.msg11450591#msg11450591) suggested:

> And first look through -
>   https://bitmain.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204875015-How-to-diagnose-S5-hashing-PCB
>
> Then if needed try -
>   https://bitmain.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203559969-My-S5-hashes-at-about-600GH-S

Oddly, I unplugged the "Power Cable to Control" (with it still running), which cut the power to it, and plugged it back in. I also sprayed the Chain #2 board with some electrical contact cleaner, and that helped. Now the little red light on that board is on!

Update: But the it's no longer on now! ☹ It just shows: "------ -------- -------- -------- " in the "ASIC status".